# Remove brackets [ ] from json response

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-security

An api returns {"authorities": [{"authority": "Employee"}]}

I want to remove [ ]

```
@RequestMapping(value=/"autho", method="GET", produces=APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity getAuthorities(final User usr){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new GetAuthorityResponse(usr.getAuthorities()));
}
```

Here getAuthorities() is from org.springframework.security which is of type `Collection<GrantedAuthority>`.
The GetAuthorityResponse casts from `Collection<GrantedAuthority>` to `Collection<CustomAuthority>`.
CustomAuthority is an enum.

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum CustomAuthority implements GrantedAuthority{
EMPLOYEE("EMPLOYEE"), EMPLOYEE1("EMPLOYEE1");
private final string authority;
// Constructor and getter
}
```

Update: This bug was already solved in previous sprints. It got reassigned mistakenly.

Comment: If the response can potentially return multiple authorities why would you want to remove the collection layer?

Comment: the name `getAuthorities` implies that multiple values will be returned, so you need a collection. If you only want one Authority to be returned, change the data model.

Comment: @Thomas By removing collection layer you mean the brackets? If yes then just a bug fix from backlog in which json response should not be an array.

Comment: @f1sh thanks for the comment. But it can return multiple values.

Comment: Then you can't simply remove `[ ]` as they represent a list in JSON.

Comment: As others already wrote, you shouldn't remove the brackets `[ ]`. Instead you should try to understand what the error __"just a bug fix from backlog in which json response should not be an array."__ is about

Comment: The `[` and `]` represent a `Collection`. For example, it might give you `[{"authorities": {...}}, {"authorities": {...}, {"authorities"}{ ... }]}`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Your response is basically an object (`{ ... }`) that contains a collection (`[...]`) of objects (so `[(`{ ... }`),(`{ ... }`),...]`). Some APIs (and UIs developed in JS) seem to skip the "collection" part if there's only one element but I'd not recommend that since you then would have to always check whether `authorities` contains a single object or a collection of objects. Additionally, supporting this would make your controller more complex and unnecessarily so. A collection with one element is still a collection and treating it that way keeps things consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some confusion around JSON.
{"authorities": [{"authority": "Employee"}]}
The [] marks a collection. Meaning it encapsulates a 'list of authorities'. This is useful, because, your JSON object can store *multiple* authorities.
for example:

```
{"authorities": [ {"authority": "Employee"}, {"authority": "CEO"},{"authority": "Admin"},{"authority": "Customer"} ]
}
```

**if you want to remove the [ ]**

if your use case, forces you to remove the collection from the JSON object, there are some simple ways of doing it.

1. If you have control over the REST API, you can change it to not return collections. However, this is **not advised** as it will most likely break something. If you are gonna do this, take it up with your team.
2. When the API returns the JSON object, you can create a new JSON object, of the given JSON object and get the first item in the collection and store it as a normal JSON value. I don't know why you would need to do this, having the collection seems great, but if you have to, that would be a *tedious* way of solving your problem.

I hope this helps! If you have questions, ask away

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You can check the updated question now.

Comment: @Adil no problem! Glad it got fixed. it's always fun to get an already fixed assignment 